# Oracle Apex User Icon Change to image

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

I am trying to change the user icon image on Desktop navigation bar. Is there a way to change it? The image to use is not available in FA(Font Apex) default.

[image]

I also tried to use the below but once save and run, icon was removed and the image was not appearing.
[image]

Comment: what Apex version are you using ?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I'm using 20.2.0.00.20

Answer (score 3):

Normally, if you are using Universal Theme, you would rely on the FA icons you have available in APEX.

[image: Normal Icon for User in Desktop Bar]

Then, to change this

Shared Components --> Navigation Bar List --> Desktop Navigation Bar

[image]

Press in `&APP_USER` ( sequence 10 ) and you will enter this section

[image]

Select the picture you want ( in my example I would select the fa-user-clock ), save your changes and run the application.

[image]

**However, if you want to use a custom image, you need to be sure that the picture fits exactly in the same space within the desktop bar. If that is not the case, Apex will remove automatically the image and will show nothing.**

Comment: Yes. I am using a different icon that was not available in Apex FA icons. I also tried .svg file as suggested by some, but still not working. Here's the icon I want to use, viewing it using IE(100% zoom), pretty sure it was not much bigger as the default apex icon size.

Comment: have you tried to debug the page or using the console in the browser to inspect the page ? I am afraid I can't help you. I never tried to change this, mostly because there are many FA icons for users, and I never found myself in the need to use something different.

Comment: Yes. Only color, position, dimension you can modify using CSS, but about the image, you need something to set it up on Apex.